# OneDrive Python SDK - create_link for fetching embedded URL

Tags: python, onedrive

OneDrive cloud provides a functionality to get embedded iFrame tags with a publicly accessible URL inside.
I'm trying to achieve the same thing using [Python OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python)

There are various features as shown on the documentation page like, uploading, downloading, renaming a file, etc.
What I'm trying to achieve here is create an embedded iFrame and get it in response. Something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online#creating-embeddable-links).

There is a function inside one of the classes of the SDK called create_link. This function is located inside the same class where other functions like `upload` are present. `onedrivesdk/request/item_request_builder.pyitem_builder_request.py`
There is also a `type` argument that can be used. I believe, `embed` would be the argument that we would pass.
However, when I execute `client.item(drive='me', id='fileid').create_link('embed')` it does not give the same result as it's shown in case of Graph API on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createlink?view=odsp-graph-online#creating-embeddable-links) page.
What should I do?

My purpose is to basically get a public URL to the excel sheet that I upload via. python code. This URL should not ask for a login.

```
def create_link(self, type):
        """Executes the createLink method

        Args:
            type (str):
                The type to use in the method request          

        Returns:
            :class:`ItemCreateLinkRequestBuilder<onedrivesdk.request.item_create_link.ItemCreateLinkRequestBuilder>`:
                A ItemCreateLinkRequestBuilder for the method
        """
        return ItemCreateLinkRequestBuilder(self.append_to_request_url("action.createLink"), self._client, type)
```

What I have right now is the item object after I upload the file.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `post` method is missing which basically submits a POST request to the server.

So, the query to create *embed links*:

```
POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "type": "embed"
}
```

could be executed via `Python OneDrive SDK` like this:

```
result = client.item(drive='me', id=item_id).create_link("embed").post()
print(result.link.web_url)
```

where `item_id` is id for drive item

Comment: That's exactly what I did yesterday after trying to dig more into the SDK. But thanks, anyway. What you have mentioned was exactly what I did. Thanks!

Comment: @VadimGremyachev how do I get `item_id` given a specific path?

Comment: @user2284570, drive items could be [addressed by url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get?view=odsp-graph-online), for instance: `GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}` which will return item details along with id

Comment: @VadimGremyachev even in the case of Onedrive for business/E3?